# Align bars of histogram centered on labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

For layouting reasons I would like to position the histgram bars centered on the labels, such that the middle of a bar is on top of the label.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = c(0,0,1,2,2,2))

ggplot(df,aes(x)) + 
    geom_histogram(binwidth=1) + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=0:2)
```

This is what it looks so far - the left side of a bar is on top of the label:

[image]

Is it possible to adjust the given snippet in such a way? (without using geom_bar instead f.x.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This doesn't require a categorical x axis, but you'll want to play a little if you have different bin widths than 1.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = c(0,0,1,2,2,2))

ggplot(df,aes(x)) + 
geom_histogram(binwidth=1,boundary=-0.5) + 
scale_x_continuous(breaks=0:2)
```

For older `ggplot2` (<2.1.0), use `geom_histogram(binwidth=1, origin=-0.5)`.

Comment: The `origin` parameter has now been depreciated in favor of `boundary`. You will need to use that if you are using `ggplot2`  2.1 or above.

Answer (score 8):

Here is one option: Calculate your own y-values, use x as a categorical x-axis and use `geom_bar(stat="identity")`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

df = data.table(x = c(0,0,1,2,2,2))

df = df[, .N, by=x]

p = ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(x), y=N)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1.0)

ggsave("barplot.png", p, width=8, height=4, dpi=120)
```

[image]

Comment: sorry, but you introduced unnecessarily a new package and ignored my request to not resort to geom_bar. please adjust or delete your answer. thanks

Answer (score 5):

The code immediately below used to work but no longer. It was preventing ggplot from assuming that bins can be evenly divided (but now ggplot2::geom_hiustogram catches this subterfuge and suggests using a different function:

```
ggplot(df,aes( factor(x) )) + 
    geom_histogram(binwidth=1 )
#Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable the x variable is discrete. Perhaps you want stat="count"?
```

So instead use:

```
ggplot(df,aes( factor(x) )) + 
    stat_count ()
```

Comment: Although this answer doesn't have any explanation (maybe should be flagged?), it has the best idea -- use factors.

Comment: Heh; now it throws an error in ggplot2 version 2.1.0