# Center Incanter histogram x-axis tick marks directly underneath bars

Tags: clojure, histogram, jfreechart, incanter

I want to align my x-axis labels in Incanter's histogram (based on JFreeChart) so that they are centered under the bars. I also want to get rid of the fractional axis tick marks.

My question is very similar to [JFreeChart: Aligning domain axis with histogram bins](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116728).

Here are related questions for other languages:

- R: [Align bars of histogram centered on labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989235/align-bars-of-histogram-centered-on-labels)
- Python: [How to center labels in histogram plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23246125/how-to-center-labels-in-histogram-plot)

```clj
(require '[incanter.charts :refer [histogram]])
(require '[incanter.core :refer [view]])
(def data [1 1 1 1 3 6])
(view (histogram data))
```

[image: Incanter Example Histogram]

P.S. The histogram is also unappealing in that the bar for 6 is to the *left* of the tick mark. The other bars are to the *right* of their tick marks!

Update: See also:

- Relevant, but I don't see a solution here: [How to center bars on tick marks](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14703&sid=747e368bf367d2315cdf911abada4f2d)

Answer (score 1):

Based on reviewing the Incanter source code and the JFreeChart documentation, I don't believe that `org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory/createHistogram` exposes the functionality to customize the axis. (I could be wrong -- perhaps you can modify the axis after using that factory method.)

In any case, I found it easier (and perhaps necessary) to use the `bar-chart` directly:

```clj
(ns custom-incanter
  (:require
   [incanter.charts :as ic]
   [incanter.core :as i]))

(defn hist
  [values title]
  {:pre [(sequential? values)]}
  (let [freq (frequencies values)
        f #(freq % 0)
        ks (keys freq)
        a (apply min ks)
        b (apply max ks)
        x-values (range a (inc b))
        x-labels (map str x-values)
        y-values (map f x-values)]
    (i/view (ic/bar-chart x-labels y-values :title title))))
```

Use it like this:

```
(hist [1 1 1 1 3 6] "Using Bar Chart")
```

[image: Custom Histogram Using Bar Chart]